# Query to get the count of items in each category (to show even empty ones with 0 items)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, count

I just wrote this query for my tables: NEWS and NEWS-CATEGORIES in order to count the items of each category:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAT.cid, CAT.c_title, N.n_category, count(*) AS cat_count
  FROM news N
 inner join news - categories CAT
    on CAT.cid = N.n_category
 GROUP BY N.n_category
```

but the problem is that it just shows me the categories which contains news! but I wana get all of the categories even the ones with empty news...

my NEWS table is:

```
nid | n_category | etc
```

my NEWS-CATEGORY table is:

```
cid | c_title | etc
```

Thanks for your help

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT CAT.cid, CAT.c_title, IFNULL(COUNT(N.n_category), 0) AS cat_count
FROM `news-categories` AS CAT
LEFT JOIN news AS N ON CAT.cid = N.n_category
GROUP BY CAT.cid
```

Things to note: 1) You have to use a column from `news` in the `COUNT()` expression, not `COUNT(*)`, so that the null match is not counted. 2) There's no need to select `N.n_category`, since that's always equal to `CAT.cid` and you're already selecting that. 3) The GROUP BY column has to be from the `news-categories` table -- you can't group by a column in the table that may not have any matching rows, since that value will always be `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CAT.cid,
    CAT.c_title,
    count(N.n_category) AS cat_count
FROM `news-categories` CAT 
    LEFT JOIN `news` N  
        ON CAT.cid = N.n_category  
GROUP BY CAT.cid,
    CAT.c_title
```

Comment: The `coalesce()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Where are the difference?

Comment: To remove the `coalesce()` you need to count the ids from the second table.  The `*` would return `1` when there is no match.

Comment: Thanks man! it works fine, @Barmar 's answer was work as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to point out that you can do this with a subquery as well:

```
SELECT CAT.cid, CAT.c_title,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news N WHERE CAT.cid = N.n_category)
FROM `news - categories` CAT;
```

Under some circumstances, this can even have better performance.

Comment: it works well dude, but I think the one @Barmar suggested was working bttr with `LEFT JOIN`